# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: magento-1.9, database

9.3.6 website. It works fine but sometime it shows SQL error and sometimes it shows many times in a day. 
here is its trace records

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Trace:
#0  /public_html/ocb/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1  /public_html/ocb/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(396): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2  /public_html/ocb/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3  /public_html/ocb/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4  /public_html/ocb/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5  /public_html/ocb/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6  /public_html/ocb/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7  /public_html/ocb/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8  /public_html/ocb/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9  /public_html/ocb/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10  /public_html/ocb/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11  /public_html/ocb/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#12  /public_html/ocb/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1357): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#13  /public_html/ocb/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1389): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#14  /public_html/ocb/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#15  /public_html/ocb/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#16  /public_html/ocb/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#17  /public_html/ocb/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(619): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#18  /public_html/ocb/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(477): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#19  /public_html/ocb/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#20  /public_html/ocb/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21  /public_html/ocb/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

please give me proper solution so that i can fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check you mysql configuration.

Comment: what to need in check in mysql configuration we got this limitations from our dedicated server with 8 GB ram -
a single mysql connection will wait 7800 to expire.
have set wait_timeout=300 and already max_allowed_packet=256M only in the server

So server saying in your site there are more then 20,000 mysql quries running thats why getting this issue they are saying optimize your database but this is magento default database and we just installed theme there is also prbm with products indexing we have uploaded 50k products there but now we cross all mysql limits, so please help to short out

Comment: have you enabled flat?

Comment: yes already enabled

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the file app/etc/env.php helped me

Comment: Rename to what? And how does your project run if you rename env.php file?

Answer (score 0):

I had this a while ago aswell.
Did you transfer your magento site from xampp to a hosting server by any chance?

My issue was Xampp generated a root user with super privileges and when i transferred over to a hosting company there wasn't any super privileges and no root user was allowed.

So when you try to run any commands you wont be able to write to SQL server.

Hope it helps